# print() method not printing correct ArrayList contents

Tags: java, arraylist

My code converts decimal to binary like so:

```
for(int i = 0; i < combinations; i++)
    {
        int binary[] = new int[numV];
        if(i == 0)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < numV; j++)
            {
                binary[j] = 0;
            }
        }
        else if(i > 0)
        {
            binary = values.get(i-1);
            for(int a = numV-1; a >= 0; a--)
            {
                System.out.println(a);
                if(binary[a]==0)
                {
                    binary[a]++;
                    break;
                }
                else
                    binary[a]=0;
            }
        }
        values.add(binary);
    }
```

As you can see, the `values` object of type `ArrayList<int[]>` stores the binary value of `i` (from the instanced integer array `binary` that gets created with each loop of *i*). However immediately after printing all the integer array representation of the binary number for each `i`, from the list, it gives the following output:

```
0000
0000
0000
0000
0000
0000
0000
0000
0000
0000
0000
0000
0000
0000
0000
0000
0000
```

My `print()` part of the code works fine. The contents in the ArrayList are incorrect and I don't know why. Can someone point out my silly mistake? Thanks.

EDIT : When I print, it prints the LAST arraylist's integer array only (when i print after the for loop). However when I print what has been just added to the array list within the for loop, its contents are correct.

COMPLETE CODE:

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class KMap extends JFrame
{
    private ArrayList<String> variableNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private String [] characters = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J"};
private ArrayList<int[]> values = new ArrayList<int[]>();
public KMap() 
{
    setTitle("Karnaugh Map for COMP 228");
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    createTopPane();
    updateVarialbes(4);
    pack();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}
public void createTopPane()
{
    JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
    topPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,10));
    JLabel numVariablesString = new JLabel();
    numVariablesString.setText("# Variables => ");
    topPanel.add(numVariablesString);
    JButton[] variableButton = new JButton[9];
    for(int i = 0; i < variableButton.length; i++)
    {
        int numV = i+2;
        variableButton[i] = new JButton();
        variableButton[i].setText(Integer.toString(numV));
        variableButton[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                removeLeftPane();
                removeRightPane();
                updateVarialbes(numV);
            }
        });

        topPanel.add(variableButton[i]);
    }
    add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
}
public void updateVarialbes(int numV)
{
    int combinations = (int) Math.pow(2,numV) + 1;
    System.out.println(combinations);
    System.out.println("New variables: " + numV);
    values.clear();
    variableNameList.clear();
    for(int i = 0; i < numV; i++)
        variableNameList.add(characters[i]);
    System.out.println();
    for(int i = 0; i < combinations; i++)
    {
        int binary[] = new int[numV];
        if(i == 0)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < numV; j++)
            {
                binary[j] = 0;
            }
        }
        else if(i > 0)
        {
            binary = values.get(i-1);
            for(int a = numV-1; a >= 0; a--)
            {
                System.out.println(a);
                if(binary[a]==0)
                {
                    binary[a]++;
                    break;
                }
                else
                    binary[a]=0;
            }
        }
        values.add(binary);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < values.get(i).length; j++)
            System.out.print(values.get(i)[j]);
        System.out.println();
    }



    createLeftPane(numV);
    createRightPane(numV);
}
public void createLeftPane(int numV)//numV = number of variables to display
{
    JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel();
    leftPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));



    JLabel variableLabel[] = new JLabel[numV];
    JPanel topLeftInnerPanel = new JPanel();
    topLeftInnerPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,numV));
    for(int i = 0; i < numV; i++)
    {
        variableLabel[i] = new JLabel();

        variableLabel[i].setText(variableNameList.get(i));
        topLeftInnerPanel.add(variableLabel[i]);
    }
    leftPanel.add(topLeftInnerPanel);



    JPanel topRightInnerPanel = new JPanel();
    JLabel functionLabel = new JLabel();
    String s = "F(";
    for(int i = 0; i < numV; i++)
    {
        s+=characters[i];
        if(i!=numV-1)
            s+=",";
    }
    s+=(")");
    System.out.println(s);
    functionLabel.setText(s);
    topRightInnerPanel.add(functionLabel);
    leftPanel.add(topRightInnerPanel);




    JPanel innerLeftPanel = new JPanel();
    innerLeftPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(values.size(), 1));
    JPanel[] innerLeftValuesPanel = new JPanel[values.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++)
    {
        innerLeftValuesPanel[i] = new JPanel();
        innerLeftValuesPanel[i].setLayout(new GridLayout(1, numV));
        for(int j = 0; j < values.get(i).length; j++)
        {
            JLabel l = new JLabel();
            l.setText(Integer.toString(values.get(i)[j]));
            innerLeftValuesPanel[i].add(l);
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < (2^numV); i++)
        innerLeftPanel.add(innerLeftValuesPanel[i]);
    leftPanel.add(innerLeftPanel);


    JPanel innerRightPanel = new JPanel();
    innerRightPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2^numV, 1));

    add(leftPanel);

}
public void removeLeftPane()
{

}
public void createRightPane(int numV)
{

}
public void removeRightPane()
{

}
```

}

Comment: what are you trying to do ? or what is not working ? I'm not sure if your code compiles too...

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Can you just use `Integer.toBinaryString(int i)` instead?

Comment: @aguibert i'm just practicing

Comment: What is numV? where is it defined? this doesn't seem to be all of the code.

Comment: numV is equal to 4. `combinations` is numV^2

Comment: Please post your complete code, not just a part of it. It is impossible to debug otherwise.

Comment: @StackFlowed There is enough code here to see what is wrong - at least for me, there is.

Comment: @AjeetKljh The problem is that you do `binary = values.get(i-1);` and this obtains the *reference* to the first int array you create and stores it into all List elements. So, finally, all 16 List elements point to the same int array, and of course eventually all elements are set to 1. - You need to *copy* the *array*, not the array object reference.

Comment: @laune code came in from edit.

Comment: @StackFlowed The code snippet in the original version was enough.

Comment: @laune voted to re open. You can answer this now.

Comment: @laune When I print what has been just added to the ArrayList object WITHIN the loop, it prints correctly. If i print every element in the list AFTER the for loop, it prints all zeroes.

Comment: @laune it seems to print every integer array as the LAST array i put in. iN this case, 1111 (i corrected the mistake with "combinations".. it said `int combinations = (int) Math.pow(2,numV); +1`, removed the one. I still don't understand

Comment: @laune nvm i get it now. thank you.

Comment: @AjeetKljh Full answer now added with detailed explanation and the fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The damage is done by the innocuous looking statement

```
binary = values.get(i-1);
```

accessing the `int[]` at the end of the `List<int[]>` that was added in the previous iteration. Now `binary` *refers* to that integer array, and the following operations modify *the array stored in the previous iteration*. Finally,

```
values.add(binary);
```

adds the reference to that array as another element to the list, which, no matter how many elements it has, refers to the same int[] with all stored references.

The fix is simple: rather than copying a *reference* to an array object, copy *the array itself*.

```
binary = Arrays.copyOf(values.get(i-1), numV );
```